# Long long data type python

Tags: python-2.7

Is there a long long equivelant data type in python as opposed to languages like C. I need it to stow large decimals. If there isn't one, is it possible to make it?

Also, I heard about a Decimal library which apparently does this. Does it go to however many places I tell it to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked about integers (a long long is an integer), but your response to Lennart suggests you really want arbitrary precision math. Google for that to get your bearings and decide what is best - there are various ways to go and you probably want more background before you decide.

One example would be python's [decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal-tutorial) where, for the number you asked about, you could set the precision to 38 using

```
getcontext().prec = 38
```

and then enter your number:

```
mynum = Decimal('22949399592991949996949929959799391997989992993979799492949799999999192996979909‌​699992999.39349979799018999992885868687758484883')
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a long long data type for humongous integers. It's called `Long`. Integers that are too long to be stored in a 32-bit integer is automatically made into Longs, so you generally don't have to think about it. However, you can explicitly create on by adding an L after the number:

```
foo = 27L
```

In Python 3 the types have been merged, so you can't explicitly create it anymore. In effect all integers are also longs.

Comment: How large can long variables go upto?

Comment: @user2442780: Until they use up all your memory.

Comment: Thanks. I assume that these can have unlimited decimal places as well? E.g. 22949399592991949996949929959799391997989992993979799492949799999999192996979909699992999.39349979799018999992885868687758484883

Comment: @user2442780 No, they are integers, like C's long long ints.

Comment: Is there a decimal equivelant by any chance (that will fit the number I put in my last comment?)

Comment: @user2442780: There is a decimal module for decimal arithmetic, but you will not have support there for values like 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.0000000000000000000000000000000001. The reason for that being that nobody needs that. I don't really think you need it either. :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32627/discussion-between-user2442780-and-lennart-regebro)